# Add keyword to existing syntax file without changing the original syntax file

Tags: syntax-highlighting

How should I ideally modify an already existing syntax file without touching the file itself (since it's normally not world writeable)?

I want to add the keyword `\autoref` to TeX's syntax highlighting, so that it is recognized by vim as `RefZone`. Basically I need to extend the following line:

```
syn region texRefZone         matchgroup=texStatement start="\\\(page\|eq\)ref{"      end="}\|%stopzone\>"    contains=@texRefGroup
```

Comment: Start with Vim's help: `:h mysyntaxfile-add`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file named `*.vim` in `~/.vim/after/syntax/` and add the desired modified line.