# Extending existing syntax highlighting system-wide

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I’m trying to figure out a way to extend existing syntax highlighting in a way that can be packaged and shipped (ie., not placed under `$HOME`)—or whether this is possible at all.

For this specific situation I’m wanting to extend [`pbOptions` of `PKGBUILD.vim`](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman-contrib/-/blob/2f555332fc8b177e588c6fa6128517689b4be239/src/vim/syntax/PKGBUILD.vim#L239) with additional options from dropped‐in "makepkg tiny" scripts. It also needs to be extended in a way that doesn’t just override the `pbOptions` since there might be multiple dropped-in scripts that would want to extend this.

I came across a couple of answers like
[How can I extend syntax highlighting with my own keywords?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/43545/how-can-i-extend-syntax-highlighting-with-my-own-keywords) and [Add keyword to existing syntax file without changing the original syntax file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5171/add-keyword-to-existing-syntax-file-without-changing-the-original-syntax-file) but they all seem to only concern user-defined extensions, not something that could be installed system wide or alongside additional extensions.

[“Syntax loading procedure” from the Vim 9.1 reference manual](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#syntax-loading) also, as far as I can tell, suggests that only a single “main” syntax file is loaded with “[a]ny other user installed FileType or Syntax autocommands” loaded last. I take this to mean that only a single (system) `.vim` syntax file is read, though this one syntax file may itself [include other syntax files](https://vimhelp.org/usr_44.txt.html#44.9).

Would it be possible by making a `PKGBUILD-script.vim` and including the `PKGBUILD.vim` in that and then use a regular expression to modify `pbOptions`? If it is, how do I ensure that this overrides `PKGBUILD.vim` as being considered the “main” syntax file? Is it possible to “stack” this so `PKGBUILD-fooscript.vim` and `PKGBUILD-barscript.vim` both get loaded without them knowing about each other?

Or is it possible to extend using some other method? Or is this not possible at all?

(This is all using a specific example, but a method that would be generally applicable would be great, if one exists.)

Comment: Why is it important to have your changes in the system config? For only one file, it's overkill but you could create a Vim plugin for your users. For system wide changes, either re-package Vim (depends on your OS' package manager), fork the Vim project or write a script that modifies the file. The three latter options will require steady maintenance and blow up if you make a mistake.

Comment: Hi @Friedrich :) As mentioned in the question (let me know if there’s a better way to phrase it if it isn’t clear), I’m not talking about overriding  _Vim’s_ configuration, but (for the included example) about overriding part of `PKGBUILD.vim` which is part of `pacman-contrib`. It’s important to have it in the system so I can have it as part of `fooscript` and `barscript`’s source repositories and to install them the proper place during packaging of them when a user installs those packages on their system.

Comment: The target location for your files should be clear from romainl's answer (with D. Ben Knoble's comment) and the [repo of pacman-contrib](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman-contrib) contains pretty much the blueprint for packaging. I was a bit surprised to see how readily pacman devs dump their Vim configs in the system. As a package manager maintainer, I guess you're above the law.

Answer (score 1):

What does "packaged and shipped" mean to you, exactly? Packaged with what? Shipped how?

The general method would be to put the lines you want in `after/syntax/PKGBUILD.vim`:

```
syn match pbOptions /foo\|bar\|baz/ contained
```

which **extends** any existing `pbOptions`.

If you want to **override** any existing `pbOptions`, you can *clear* `pbOptions` before redefining it with your own patterns:

```
syn clear pbOptions
syn match pbOptions /foo\|bar\|baz/ contained
```

From there, the file can be distributed however you want, as a Vim plugin or, like that `PKGBUILD.vim` you linked to, as part of some package, via your system's package manager.

--- EDIT ---

> How would this single file work with separate packages wanting to extend the same option?

There are two parts to this question.

### The importance of sourcing order

The last script wins.

If none of the sourced scripts uses some variant of `syn clear pbOptions`, then all the `pbOptions` definitions will work together as one giant regular expression. This is the best case scenario, where everyone is being a good respectful citizen.

If any of the sourced scripts uses a variant of `syn clear pbOptions`, then all the `pbOptions` patterns defined *before* are ignored. This is the worst case scenario, where everyone tries to control what's going on… without really being able to.

### Several packages

As pointed out in the comments, it is possible to split a given syntax into several scripts:

```
after/syntax/PKGBUILD/foo.vim
after/syntax/PKGBUILD/bar.vim
after/syntax/PKGBUILD/baz.vim
```

So it is possible to imagine the `pacman-contrib` package installing:

```
syntax/PKGBUILD.vim
```

your `foo` package installing:

```
after/syntax/PKGBUILD/foo.vim
```

and my `bar` package installing:

```
after/syntax/PKGBUILD/bar.vim
```

which would all work together seemlessly.

But the *proper* way to do all this, no matter how you get Vim plugins, is to use the `:help package` feature.

Instead of installing stuff directly at the root of `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/`, the `pacman-contrib` package should install its stuff under:

```
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/pacman-contrib/
```

your `foo` package should install it under:

```
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/foo/
```

and my `bar` package should install its stuff under:

```
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/bar/
```

which, as long as package names are unique (which is mostly the package manager/registry's responsibility), guarantees that they will—*at least*—not overwrite each other.

So, in concrete terms…

1. The people in charge of the `pacman-contrib` package should do the following move:

   ```
   # before
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/PKGBUILD.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/SRCINFO.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/PKGBUILD.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/indent/PKGBUILD.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/PKGBUILD.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/SRCINFO.vim

   # after
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/pacman-contrib/start/pacman/ftdetect/PKGBUILD.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/pacman-contrib/start/pacman/ftdetect/SRCINFO.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/pacman-contrib/start/pacman/ftplugin/PKGBUILD.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/pacman-contrib/start/pacman/indent/PKGBUILD.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/pacman-contrib/start/pacman/syntax/PKGBUILD.vim
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/pacman-contrib/start/pacman/syntax/SRCINFO.vim
   ```
2. You should package your syntax script so that it is installed there:

   ```
   /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/freso-stuff/start/pacman/after/syntax/PKGBUILD.vim
   ```

   with `freso-stuff` being whatever unique-ish name you want.
3. Others should do the same.

Comment: In this case I’m referring to Arch Linux/pacman packages, so using a `PKGBUILD` file describing the packaging and using `makepkg` to actually take the source and manipulate it into an archive that a user can then `pacman -U` to install.

Would `after/syntax/PKGBUILD.vim` be e.g. `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/syntax/PKGBUILD.vim`? How would this single file work with separate packages wanting to extend the same option (e.g., `fooscript` wanting to do `syn match pbOptions /foo/ contained` and `barscript` wanting to do `syn match pbOptions /bar/ contained`)?

Comment: The names on these files can contain arbitrary extra text (like `PKGBUILD_myplugin.vim`), so that’s how you’d handle multiples (I think you can also put them in a directory named after the ft, but I’m not sure.) As far as packaging goes, typically you’d have a plugin provides files as if they were under a runtimepath (like many plugins on GitHub; see also `:help packages`). Then you’d want to provide a way to install those files to somewhere in the runtimepath (if you’re packaging for a distro, somewhere in that distro’s system files, probably).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble "I think you can also put them in a directory named after the ft"* - that's correct according to `:help mysyntaxfile-add`, last paragraph.

Comment: Regarding the edit: I think the package's name is `pacman-contrib` with `pacman` being the package manager itself and -contrib containing the stuff for its development. I could be wrong, I'm only an Arch user, not a contributor. From my point of view, this answer looks pretty complete.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer with the presumably correct `pacman-contrib`.

Comment: In case `pacman-contrib` maintainers refuse to change directories, it [looks as if you could](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman-contrib/-/blame/master/configure.ac?ref_type=heads#L15) call `configure --with-vim-dir=/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack/pacman-contrib/start/pacman/` (or even your user's Vim dir)